# Prove the centralizers of 2 similar matrices have the same dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

I'm struggling a little bit with this question and would really appreciate a nod in the right direction!

I need to show that if $A=PBP^{-1}$, then the centralizers of $A$ and $B$ have the same dimension.

I've tried representing one by the other (but it doesn't really seem doable) and I realise that they have the same eigenvalues which might be useful.

I understand that I probably need to prove a bijection from one to the other but I'm not really sure where to start. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: $X\mapsto P^{-1}XP$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote
$$
\forall A \in \Bbb M_n ,Z(A) = \{M \in \Bbb M_n \mid MA=AM\}.
$$
If $A=PBP^{-1}$ and $M \in Z(A)$, we have
\begin{align}
MA=AM &\iff MPBP^{-1}=PBP^{-1}M\\
&\iff P^{-1}MPB=BP^{-1}MP\\
&\iff M'B=BM'
\end{align}
with $M'=P^{-1}MP$. This gives us a hint: let
$$
\phi_P : Z(A) \to Z(B) 
$$
such that $\phi_P(M)=M'=P^{-1}MP$. We see that $\phi$ is linear and that
$$
\phi_{P^{-1}} \circ \phi_{P} =\phi_{P} \circ \phi_{P^{-1}}=\text{id}.
$$
So $\phi$ is an isomorphism. This shows that $Z(A) \cong Z(B)$.